# Is blocking the ultimate strategy?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

Just bought and glanced through Injustice 1.

Went through the Tutorial.

And while I suck at blocking and can't seem to execute these Reversal attacks correctly... I start thinking that if both players had reflexes of a pantheer and could always block... neither would have any reason to attack?? Each attack can be blocked (throws can be broken). When you block an attack you can follow up with a reversal attack which, if executed correctly, cannot be blocked by the enemy since he's stunned. (correct me if i'm wrong). So the player who's attack is at disadvantage and a person who blocks and reversals is always at advantage. Am I right?

Can an AI that is set to Always block, with Reversal setting ON and throw break setting ON be defeated by any means?